# Under what circumstances would these 3 queries return different number of results?

Tags: join, query, explain, where

Hello I have the following question:

```
Query 1:

SELECT b.id,
    (
    SELECT SUM(cb.invoice_amount) AS sum
    FROM payment_lines cb
    WHERE cb.batch_id = b.id
    ) AS batch_total_invoice_amount
FROM batches b;


Query 2:

SELECT b.id, SUM(cb.invoice_amount) 
FROM batches b 
 LEFT JOIN payment_lines cb ON b.id = cb.batch_id 
GROUP BY b.id
ORDR BY b.id desc;


Query 3:


SELECT batch_id, sum(invoice_amount) 
FROM payment_lines
GROUP BY batch_id
ORDER BY batch_id desc;
```

Comment: Dependent of the tables and keys answer may vary. If there are rows in payment_lines but not in batches, third query will return rows where as first and second query will not

Comment: The 1st and 2nd are equivalent, assuming batch(id) is the primary/unique key.

Answer (score 0):

The first query may return rows from batches where no payment-lines exist, ie. an outer join.

Answer (score 0):

Investigate:

> ```
> CREATE TABLE batches (id INT, name VARCHAR(200));
> INSERT INTO batches VALUES
> (1, 'name 1-1'),
> (1, 'name 1-2'),
> (2, 'name 2'),
> (3, 'name 3'),
> (4, 'name 4'),
> (NULL, 'name NULL');
>
> CREATE TABLE payment_lines (batch_id INT, invoice_amount INT);
> INSERT INTO payment_lines VALUES
> (1,100),
> (1,200),
> (2,111),
> (2,222),
> (3,NULL),
> (5, 123),
> (NULL,456);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT b.id,
>     (
>     SELECT SUM(cb.invoice_amount) AS sum
>     FROM payment_lines cb
>     WHERE cb.batch_id = b.id
>     ) AS batch_total_invoice_amount
> FROM batches b
> ORDER BY b.id desc;
>
> SELECT b.id, SUM(cb.invoice_amount) 
> FROM batches b 
>  LEFT JOIN payment_lines cb ON b.id = cb.batch_id 
> GROUP BY b.id
> ORDER BY b.id desc;
>
> SELECT batch_id, sum(invoice_amount) 
> FROM payment_lines
> GROUP BY batch_id
> ORDER BY batch_id desc;
> ```
>
> ```
>   id | batch_total_invoice_amount
> ---: | -------------------------:
>    4 |                       null
>    3 |                       null
>    2 |                        333
>    1 |                        300
>    1 |                        300
> null |                       null
>
>   id | SUM(cb.invoice_amount)
> ---: | ---------------------:
>    4 |                   null
>    3 |                   null
>    2 |                    333
>    1 |                    600
> null |                   null
>
> batch_id | sum(invoice_amount)
> -------: | ------------------:
>        5 |                 123
>        3 |                null
>        2 |                 333
>        1 |                 300
>     null |                 456
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=40f85ecd91dfa4e0b9d7956c87342288)*